# How do I switch back into third person after being in first person in Mad Max

Tags: mad-max

I accidentally switched into first person and don't know how to return to the third person again.

Comment: I am playing on a PS4, there is no V key

Comment: According to the answer in the linked question, the PS4 equivalent is to "quickly tap down on the d-pad twice."

Answer (score 0):

Try tapping the <kbd>V</kbd> key to switch between first and third person view in vehicles.

Here are all the keybindings from the manual: http://support.feralinteractive.com/docs/en/madmax/latest/steam/manual/#!spread4